# Lista de lista para DataFrame - Parenteses atrapalhando

Tags: python, lista, dataframe

Eu preciso transformar uma lista de listas em DataFrame, colocando título em cada coluna. O problema é que os "()" englobando cada lista (que no caso seriam as linhas) está atrapalhando.

```
from datetime import datetime

head = ["DATA", "PRODUTO", "VALOR", "DESCRIÇÃO", "RECEBIMENTO", "TIPO"]

#o problema está nos parenteses que engloba a lista de dados
l = [   [(datetime(2022, 9, 14), "HotWheels", "13.99", "Novo", "Compra", "Brinquedo")],
        [(datetime(2022, 9, 15), "Jack Daniels", "139.99", "Novo", "Presente", "Bebida")]
]
```

após fazer isso:

```
import pandas as pd

l_df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=head)

print(l_df)
```

Esta deveria ser a saída

```
        DATA       PRODUTO   VALOR DESCRIÇÃO RECEBIMENTO       TIPO
0 2022-09-14     HotWheels   13.99      Novo      Compra  Brinquedo
1 2022-09-15  Jack Daniels  139.99      Novo    Presente     Bebida
```

Mas da um erro, este:

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py:982, in _finalize_columns_and_data(content, columns, dtype)
    981 try:
--> 982     columns = _validate_or_indexify_columns(contents, columns)
    983 except AssertionError as err:
    984     # GH#26429 do not raise user-facing AssertionError

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py:1030, in _validate_or_indexify_columns(content, columns)
   1028 if not is_mi_list and len(columns) != len(content):  # pragma: no cover
   1029     # caller's responsibility to check for this...
-> 1030     raise AssertionError(
   1031         f"{len(columns)} columns passed, passed data had "
   1032         f"{len(content)} columns"
   1033     )
   1034 elif is_mi_list:
   1035 
   1036     # check if nested list column, length of each sub-list should be equal

AssertionError: 6 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/ken/KR/Programação/teste.ipynb Cell 2 in <cell line: 3>()
...
--> 985     raise ValueError(err) from err
    987 if len(contents) and contents[0].dtype == np.object_:
    988     contents = _convert_object_array(contents, dtype=dtype)

ValueError: 6 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns
```

Comment: Por que você coloca uma tupla dentro de uma lista que está dentro de outra lista? Talvez seja esse o problema.

Comment: Então, os dados são importados, não dando pra mexer neles um por um.

Answer (score -2):

Isto deve resolver:

```
pd.DataFrame([list(value) for sub_l in l for value in sub_l], columns=head)
```

O código foi simulado com a sua entrada e produziu a saída solicitada.